# Java Persistence api: class uses non-entity class as target entity in the relationship attribute

Tags: java, persistence

Good day. I try to have many-to-many dependencies with persistence api.
I fill an new user data and try to add it to the database, but get an exception:

`Exception Description: [class main.java.entities.User] uses a non-entity [class main.java.entities.UserAccounts] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field accounts].`

I try to use difference values for @ManyToMany annotation in `name` section such as `bank_user_accounts` and `userAccounts`. Second value is a name of unit in `persistence.xml`. But this trouble still exists.

User class:

```
@Entity(name="bank_users")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name = "bank_user_accounts",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
  )
  private List<UserAccounts> accounts;
}
```

UserAccounts class:

```
@Entity(name="bank_user_accounts")
public class UserAccounts {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private int userId;

  @Column(name = "account_id")
  private int accountId;
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="users" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>main.java.entities.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="deleted" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="deleted" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="deleted" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

  <persistence-unit name="userAccounts" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>main.java.entities.UserAccounts</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="deleted" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="deleted" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="deleted" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: So, i use this as example and now all works great https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between the `User` and `UserAccounts` sound rather `@OneToMany` or simply an embeddable class.

`@ManyToMany` should have the annotation on both sides (bidirectional) and should have the `mappedBy` attribute set on one side, to point to the other side's property name referencing this entity as a collection.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have observed in your code is you have used manytomany annotation in User class but you have not used in userAccounts class. To achieve ManyToMany relation, both the entities should be annotated with ManyToMany.

Comment: It's an error too, there should be List<Account>, and UserAccounts - class for link User and Account that presents many-to-many refs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (although maybe outdated) that you have a reference from one persistence unit to another. You can easily put both to the same unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="users" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>main.java.entities.User</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.UserAccounts</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="deleted" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="deleted" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="deleted" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```